# HIbernate outer join without mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 2 tables and i am trying to use join without any mapping between the classes
(StData and ApFlow).I have a query like this and i get the desired result in database. 
Is it possible to do without mapping, if so how to do. Please someone help me. 
With this query is am getting `QueryException: Unable to resolve path [ApFlow.ApNumber]`.

```
session.createQuery("FROM StData "
                + "LEFT OUTER JOIN ApFlow "
                + "ON StData.Apart = ApFlow.Apart and StData.StTitle = ApFlow .StTitle "
                + "WHERE ApFlow.ApNumber= :ApNumber and ApFlow.Apart= :Apart")

        .setParameter("ApNumber",ApNumber)
        .setParameter("Apart", Apart)
        .list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Hibernate 5.1+:
[Join unrelated entities in JPA](http://blog.anthavio.net/2016/03/join-unrelated-entities-in-jpa.html)

And, probably, you need to add aliases

```
"FROM StData st"
    + "LEFT OUTER JOIN ApFlow flow "
    + "ON st.Apart = flow.Apart and st.StTitle = flow.StTitle "
    + "WHERE flow.ApNumber = :ApNumber and flow.Apart = :Apart"
```

This query can be simulated using a cross product. But, keep in mind that it is not true `left join` (cause of `null` values). This is more like an `inner join`.

```
"FROM StData st, ApFlow flow"
    + "WHERE st.Apart = flow.Apart and st.StTitle = flow.StTitle "
    + "and flow.ApNumber= :ApNumber and flow.Apart= :Apart"
```

Comment: In Hibernate 4 have to use mapping ? Any other choice available ?

Comment: @user7620991 Yes, It is mandatory to have the mapping for a join in Hibernate 4. Probably, you can rewrite your query using inner select.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am going to accept your answer. I am new to sql/hibernate could you please show it. Would be very helpful.

Comment: @user7620991 I am sorry. It was just an assumption. Maybe, something like `select FROM StData st ... where st.StTitle in(select flow.StTitle from ApFlow flow ... )`. But, It is need to think about `st.Apart = flow.Apart`. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a cross product.

Comment: The one in answer worked. But i did not understand what you are saying in above comment. But i was trying to write a query like that.

Comment: @user7620991 I meant this simplified query `select FROM StData st  where st.StTitle in(select flow.StTitle from ApFlow flow where flow.ApNumber = :ApNumber and flow.Apart = :Apart)`